# PHP preg_match + regex not identifying non-numeric input?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to prevent non numbers from being inserted into my database, preferably not exceeding 6 digits. Currently my regex is failing to match and exit out of the PHP script if non-numeric characters are entered, and consequently, the data gets inserted into the database. I cannot figure out why, as its stated everywhere online that this solution should be correct. The data that's coming through is an array of characters, formed from an exploded string of those characters if that helps.

PHP:

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i <= $count ; ++$i)
    {
       if (!preg_match("/^\d+$/", $number_array[$i]))
        {
            exit();
        }
        else
        {....
```

Comment: Sorry, could you please clarify the rules? What strings are valid and which are invalid?

Comment: ones with only numbers are valid :)

Comment: So, `if (preg_match('~^\d+$~D', $s)) { echo "Valid"; } else { echo "Invalid"; }`

Comment: I used `preg_match('~^\d+$~D', $number_array[$i])` but it would come up invalid to numeric input aswell unfortunately

Comment: Why not use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php?

Comment: Did you give up???

Comment: I redesigned my system to use a different method, so strange

Answer (score 1):

Without the loop, get all of the values that are numbers between 1 and 6 digits from the array into another array and then compare with the original array:

```
if(preg_grep('/^\d{1,6}$/', $number_array) != $number_array) {
    exit;
} else {
    //something
}
```

It's a bit longer, but you could also filter out the values that are not numbers between 1 and 6 digits and compare with the original:

```
(array_filter($number_array, function($v) {
                                 return ctype_digit($v) && (strlen($v) < 7);
                             }) != $number_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be the regex you want, it matches all strings of numbers between 1 and 6 digits.

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i <= $count ; ++$i)
{
   if (!preg_match("/^\d{1,6}$/m", $number_array[$i]))
    {
        exit();
    }
    else
    {....
```

So `156546` will match but these won't.

```
1565467
156546s
s15654
156546sa
asdfasdfa
```

Comment: Still doesn't exit when non-numeric are used for me, so strange

Comment: That's strange, the regex is correct. Are you sure it doesn't reach the exit? Have you tried putting and `echo` just before?

Comment: Yes there's a header redirect just before the exit 

Comment: Well it obviously works, there is something else in your code, maybe it never reaches the loop, who knows https://3v4l.org/j7PU5

Comment: It goes through the full loop cycle, and inserts into the database, I agree with you it should work though, I'll have to grind it out, thankyou anyway :)